# Deleting an item from FlatList fails with "TypeError: (0, _activities.default) is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a screen that displays a `FlatList` of custom `ActivityItem` components to which I am trying to assign an `onDelete` action:

```
const TravelScreen = props => {
    const myActivities = useSelector(state => state.activities.userActivities);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data={myActivities}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={itemData => (
                <ActivityItem 
                    transportation={itemData.item.transportation} 
                    startTime={itemData.item.startTime} 
                    endTime={itemData.item.endTime} 
                    onEdit={() => {}} 
                    onDelete={() => {
                        dispatch(removeActivity(itemData.item.id));
                    }} 
                />
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

store/actions/activities.js:

```
export const REMOVE_ACTIVITY = 'REMOVE_ACTIVITY';

export const removeActivity = id => {
    return {type: REMOVE_ACTIVITY, id: id};
};
```

store/reducers/activities.js:

```
import ACTIVITIES from '../../data/dummy-activity-data';
import REMOVE_ACTIVITY from '../actions/activities';

const initialState = {
    allActivities: ACTIVITIES,
    userActivities: ACTIVITIES.filter(activity => activity.userId === 'u1')
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REMOVE_ACTIVITY:
            const updatedUserActivities = {...state.items};
            delete updatedUserActivities[action.id];
            return {
                ...state,
                userActivities: updatedUserActivities
            };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share how are you importing removeActivity?
Are you importing it like this?

```
import removeActivity from './actitivties'
```

If so try importing it like this:

```
import { removeActivity } from './activities'
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the error. However, my delete button still doesn't remove items from the `FlatList`. Do you see anything wrong with store/reducers/activities.js?

Comment: Is that the actual code of the reducer? From where does `state.items` come from? I see only userActivities.
But if I assume userActivities is an array then I would reccomend returning the filtered array: 
`const updatedUserActivities = state.activities.filter(x => x.id !== action.id)`

Comment: The delete keyword is used to delete keys from an object and I wouldn't recommend using it with arrays